# Open source space time series database management system

Tags: open-source-gis, time, software-recommendations

I am aware of the existence of space time DBMSs such as [Druid](http://druid.io/), [InfluxDB](http://influxdb.org/) or [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/). Is there anything like it for spatially explicit data? A time series extension for a common spatial DBMS (say, PostGIS) could do it; as well as a spatial extension to an existing time series DBMS.

Comment: A student won a competition developing a postgres/postgis extension to handle dynamic phenomena. I don't know if he published his code but, nevertheless, you could contact him. http://52north.org/news/student-innovation-prize-winners-announced